# How to search int[] Array in list or Entity?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

How to search int[]  QTaskId  in Entity. i try to make below but i can not

```
void (Run(int[] QTaskId)
{
 var Que = calculateCtx.QTaskRelations.Where(q => q.QTaskId.Contains(QTaskId)).Select(q => q);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look the other way around: you have to search the "QTaskId" array for "q.QTaskId":

```
void (Run(int[] QTaskId)
{
 var Que = calculateCtx.QTaskRelations.Where(q => QTaskId.Contains(q.QTaskId)).Select(q => q);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you've just got the contains wrong. Instead of this:

```
Where(q => q.QTaskId.Contains(QTaskId))
```

try this:

```
Where(q => QTaskId.Contains(q.QTaskId))
```

I would also suggest changing your parameter name to something more easily understandable, such as "validTaskIds" (note the plural, as well as the camelCased name). Then:

```
Where(q => validTaskIds.Contains(q.QTaskId))
```